# Use of the negative "couldn't" in a positive request

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

> We were told to invite a certain person by Lord Garon. Seeing you here, we wondered if you couldn’t help us out.

He means to ask him for help, right?
Is it a typo?
In Polish, though, you can easily phrase it like that.

Should it have been worded using a question tag instead?

> we wondered if you could help us out, couldn't you

My mother language isn't English, and I'm not quite sure about some stuff.

Comment: It is a typo. You're right.

Comment: Correction then ?

Comment: We were told by Lord Garon to invite a certain person. Seeing you here, we wondered if you could help us out.

Comment: Or, couldn't but help us out. (The difference between those might convert this from proof-reading into an on-topic question.)

Comment: I don't believe this is a typo. Both "we wondered if you couldn't ... " and "we wondered if you could ... " are alternative forms of the same question. The former somewhat expects a negative reply, and because of this assumption reads as more polite, cautious, etc. In this way it operates similarly to the negation in  "You couldn't help me, could you?".

Comment: @remnant Only in AmE, I think. I believe BrE doesn't work like that.

Comment: British 'politeness' - suggesting they couldn't help out first is so they won't feel bad saying no, and the asker will be pleased if they do help out...

Comment: I'd vote it isn't a typo. The speaker is indeed being extremely cautious  and wouldn't want to come off as presumptuous.

Comment: There are nuances. Using "we wondered if you *couldn’t* help us out" implies a lower expectation than "we wondered if you *could* help us out" - which is a bit more demanding.

Comment: Note to reviewers: I don't consider this question to be *proofreading*. It's a question about using the negative form *couldn't* when making a positive request. The [word-choice] and [word-usage] tags are apt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a valid alternative way of asking the same question.

The article [Request Strategies Across Languages](http://carla.umn.edu/speechacts/requests/strategies.html) from the University of Minnesota calls this a *request mitigator*:

> Mitigating the face-threatening nature of requests can also be achieved by use of downgraders. The speaker might indicate being pessimistic with regard to the outcome of the request (negative usage)...
>
> *Look, excuse me. I wonder if you **wouldn’t** mind dropping me home?*

[Pragmatics and the English Language](https://books.google.at/books?id=wz6ICgAAQBAJ&pg=PT231&l=&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Jonathan Culpeper describes this as "syntactic downgrading through negation" e.g.

> *I **couldn't** get a drink, could I?*

This book notes that this construction, among others, occurs more frequently in Irish English compared to British English, and more frequently in British English compared to American English.